# Google Docs API for creating a blank document does not create anything. How do I make it create a blank Google Docs file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to create a Google Docs file using the API with Python.

I have followed every instruction on their API Guides and Reference page.

Including creating their quickstart script

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

    title = 'My Document'
    body = {
        'title': title
    }
    doc = service.files() \
        .create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        doc.get('title')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected a Google Docs file to be created but instead the script returned: Created document with title: None.

There are no errors it returns but clearly something is missing for it to not create the file.

I am quite frustrated because I spent 9 hours trying to get Google Drive's very own script to work. The code is a direct copy-paste from the Google Drive and Docs API documentation except for where I changed the scope from "SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']" to "SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']" because with the former it was crashing and their API documentation advises to use the latter as the scope when trying to create files.

Edit:

Current script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    title = 'My Document'
    body = {
        'title': title
    }
    doc = service.documents() \
        .create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        doc.get('title')))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error:

Traceback

```
 (most recent call last):
  File "create-teamwork-sops.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "create-teamwork-sops.py", line 131, in main
    .create(body=body).execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 855, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Notes: every time the value of SCOPES is changed, the file token.pickle needs to be deleted, and when the script runs it will ask you to log into Google Drive and will create a new token.pickle file, which will allow the new scope to be taken into account.

Working script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    # service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # title = 'My Document'
    # body = {
        # 'title': title
    # }
    # doc = service.documents() \
        # .create(body=body).execute()
    # print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        # doc.get('title')))

    # get folder ID
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
            print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
            if file.get('name')=="SOPs":
                folder_id=file.get('id')
                break
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

    # create Google Docs file in folder
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'my doc 2',
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    # media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                            # mimetype='image/jpeg',
                            # resumable=True)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        # media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? Which do you want to create new Google Document using Drive API or Docs API?

Comment: The documentation shows creating the file using the Google Docs API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries. I am using the Google Docs API with the goal to create Google Docs files in my Google Drive folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand your goal. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5):

- You want to create new Google Document using Docs API.
- You want to put the created new Google Document to the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with Python.

I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, when new Google Document is created by Docs API, the Document is the root folder. So when you want to directly create the new Document to the specific folder, please use Drive API. The modified script is as follows.

#### From:

```
body = {
    'title': title
}
```

#### To:

```
body = {
    'name': title,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    'parents': ['### folder ID ###']
}
```

- Please set the folder ID to `'parents': ['### folder ID ###']`.

#### Note:

- Of course, after new Document was created to the root folder by Docs API, the file can be moved to the specific folder using Drive API. In this case, 2 API calls are used. So I proposed above modification.
- If you want to create new Google Document using Docs API, please modify as follows. In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to set and get values for Google Document using Google Docs API.

  - From

    ```
    doc = service.files() \
            .create(body=body).execute()
    ```
  - To

    ```
    serviceForDocs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    doc = serviceForDocs.documents().create(body=body).execute()
    ```

#### References:

- [Method: documents.create of Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- [Files: create of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Thank you! I am now getting the following error: HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Comment: @Sebastien Michaud Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. The error message means that the scopes cannot be used for the method. But, unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current script. So can you add your current script for replicating your issue to your question? By this, I would like to confirm the reason of the new issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I have now added my current script to the post. Thank you. I tried your solution as well but get the same error.

Comment: @Sebastien Michaud Thank you for replying and adding the script. From your script, I think that your script works using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`. So I thought that in your situation, the access token and refresh token in the file of `token.pickle` might not be updated. So please do as follows. 1. Delete the file of `token.pickle`. 2. Run the script and authorize the scopes again. In my environment, I could confirm that your script worked. So if other error occurs, please show it.

Comment: That worked. I forgot the token.pickle file had to be deleted when changing the scope so that it gets recreated with a new token. I was able to create a new Google Docs file in my root folder in Google Drive but how do I create a file inside a folder? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastien Michaud Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I have to apologize about your new question. Because I had already answered for it. If you cannot understand about it, that is due to my poor English skill. Can you confirm my answer again? You are required to use Drive API. If you cannot understand my English. Please tell me.

Comment: No worries Tanaike, I have managed to create a Google Docs file in the folder I wanted. I will update my post with the working script I am currently using. Thank you again!

Comment: @Sebastien Michaud Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.